# how to retrieve the all the values of a super column in a set rowID from a columnfamily in Hector Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, super, hector

I want to retrieve the different row id values depending on super column name.
For that purpose I have used this code

```
    SuperColumnQuery<String, String, String, String> superColumnQuery =
            HFactory.createSuperColumnQuery(keyspaceOperator, se, se,se,se);
    superColumnQuery.setColumnFamily(COLUMN_FAMILY).setKey(rowID).setSuperName(superColumnName);
    QueryResult<HSuperColumn<String, String, String>> result = superColumnQuery.execute();
    //rowID contains a list of rows separated by ','
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're trying to select row keys based on column names, I'd venture to guess that your data model is backwards.  You should generally be moving from the outside in -- select on row key, then on supercolumn name, then on column name.  Otherwise you're going to be stuck iterating over rows in your code trying to match a column name, instead of using the Cassandra engine to select what you need.  This approach is never going to scale.

So I'd suggest redoing your data model -- or if you need to have it this way, consider adding another ColumnFamily that serves as an index for the first.  Contrary to old-school SQL databases, the credo in NoSQL dbs like Cassandra is "If you're denormalizing -- you're doing it right".

Comment: Eugene its not a good practice to sub slice a super column. That's why even the cassandra community is deprecating this technique Super Column, i guess. So its better not to waste our time and look for the new technique, composite column which eventually solves all the issues.